# SWTBot - Could not find a display - Eclipse 2020

Tags: java, eclipse, swtbot

I'm trying to use SWTBot on Eclipse and run into some trouble when following some tutorials and exemple.
On eclipse 2020-09 whenever I try to run a code I get an error due to the method SWTBot() to initialize the bot.
[Vogella Code In Eclipse 2020](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuiB5.png)

It happened with several tutorials or exemple I followed, like these ones:

https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/SWTBot/article.html

https://wiki.eclipse.org/SWTBot/UsersGuide

[Testing SWT GUI with SWTBot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716174/testing-swt-gui-with-swtbot)

When trying these on a previous version of eclipse 2019-06 it works (or in vogella's exemple, the error are no longer due to the initialization of the bot but to missing elements in UI).
[Vogella Code In Eclipse 2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Gr2I.png)

About the code I'm testing:
For vogella it's  the one in the section 4.3 Create Test.

In the userGuide it's the one in  section "Getting started with SWTBot for Eclipse Plugins".

About my run Configurations:
On the 2020 I tried with both JUnit plugin test and SWTBot Test. I was careful to not run the test in UI thread as said in documentation. I run the tests with java 1.8 and java 14.

On the 2019 version I tried only with the JUnit Plugin test and without thread UI, I run the tests with java 1.8.

So what I'm looking for is a way to run my tests with SWTBot on the 2020 version. I couldn't find any information about such error.
I will gladly provide more informations if you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was not due to a different version of eclipse but to a specific module in another project in my workspace. I remove it and now it's ok.